# Access nativescript list-view programmatically

Tags: javascript, nativescript

Seeing that this binding issue: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8219 will not go away anytime soon, I am looking into setting the class name programatically from a function using the itemTemplateSelector event but do not know how to access the listView. Here is my test code:

```
<ListView id="listView"  row="3" items="{{ listArray }}"  class="list-group" 
   itemTemplateSelector="selectItemTemplate">
<ListView.itemTemplates>
    <template key="even">
        <StackLayout id="even">
            <Label text="{{ 'Name: ' + name }}" class="h2" textWrap="true"/>
            <Label text="{{ 'Age: ' + age }}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </template>
    <template key="odd">
        <StackLayout id="odd">
            <Label text="{{ 'Name: ' + name }}" class="h2" textWrap="true" />
            <Label text="{{ 'Age: ' + age }}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </template>
  </ListView.itemTemplates>
</ListView>
```

//list-page.js

I know I can do this by returning template keys:

```
exports.selectItemTemplateAge = (item, index, items) => {
  return item.age > 18 ? "even" : "odd";
}
```

but how can I access the listView page elements from within the event:

```
exports.selectItemTemplateAge = (item, index, items) => {
 let listView = page.getViewById("listView");
 let label =  listView.getChild("label");
 return label.class = "classname";
}
```

I found this example http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=224 but that is using a button tap withing the list view. I want to access the list view items and then set classes from with the selectItemTemplateAge. I have have prepared a simple example on https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=X5MRsL&v=6. This example does not return key value for the event but seeks to modify listItem class. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

**EDIT**

searching the internet and reading the docs I was able to get a little closer. Using an loaded event on the listview i was able to trigger this using the awesome nativescript-dom-free plugin:

```
exports.getListItems = (args) => {
//let p = args.object;
//console.log(p);
// let stacklayout = page.getViewById('stack0');
// console.log(stacklayout);
 setTimeout(() => {
    let c = 0;
    page.runAgainstClasses("list1Stack", function(elem) { 
        c++;
        // console.log(c);
        // console.log(elem.getChildrenCount());
        // console.log(elem.getChildAt(2).class);
        console.log(`${c} === ${elem.id}`);
        if (c === 6) {

            elem.getChildAt(2).class = "show";
        }
     })
}, 300);
 }
```

Comment: You should not edit the class name programatically on label when it's from list view. You should bind the class name in your template instead, otherwise you will encounter unwanted issues when the list items are reused as you scroll down / up.

Comment: That is true. I was trying to find a work around for the issue above. It appears there is none.

Comment: It turns out that there is an hack for it: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/7867